# How to get the count of selected items in Kendo Multi Select Control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, kendo-ui, multi-select

What is the best way to get the count of selected Items in the Kendo multi select control?

I've tried:

```
multiSelect.dataItems().count()
```

and

```
multiSelect.value().count()
```

and neither work? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `multiSelect.value()` returns an array so use `length`, same for `multiSelect.dataItems()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using `multiSelect.value()` will give you an array of the selected items. You can then get the `.length` off the array:

```
var count = multiSelect.value().length;
```

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/multiselect#methods-value

and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: if you're doing serverfiltering AND serverPaging, then the value() does't return the correct items. It will only count what's on the DOM!!!

Answer (score 1):

It might help to others

```
var multiSelectItems = $('#MultiselectCollection').data('kendoMultiSelect');
var count = multiSelectItems .value().length;
```